# What is the implementation of std::min() that has a single parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I saw the following statement in a code:

```
std::min(0);
```

The closest definition I can find is:

```
template <class T> constexpr T min (initializer_list<T> il);
```

So far I found the implementation in `stl_algo.h`:

```
template<typename _Tp>
    _GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR
    inline _Tp
    min(initializer_list<_Tp> __l)
    { return *std::min_element(__l.begin(), __l.end()); }
```

I used to think that `std::min()` only calculates the minimum of two items. Can anyone explain to me what does it actually do? And what is an `initializer_list`?

Comment: does that even compile? which compiler?

Comment: It compiles both on gcc 8.3 and clang 8.0

Comment: @MerajalMaksud [it doesn't compile for me](http://ideone.com/DSc5hi) using gcc 8.3: "*error: no matching function for call to ‘min(int)’*" and for the 1-param version: "*note: mismatched types ‘std::initializer_list<_Tp>’ and ‘int’*"

Comment: Use `c++11` or `c++14`

Comment: @MerajalMaksud ideone does, as evident by the reported candidates using `constexpr`

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in your title, the minimum of a set of numbers when the set contains one number is the number itself. That's easy for me to understand. I hope it is for you to understand too.

> I used to think that std::min() only calculates the minimum of two items.

It used to be but since C++11, it has changed. Since C++11, there is

```
template< class T >
T min( std::initializer_list<T> ilist );
```

and a few variants. It can be used as:

```
std::min({num1, num2, ..., numn});
```

I am surprised that

```
std::min(0);
```

works for you. It should not. Perhaps it is supported by g++ as a non-standard extension. However, you should be able to use

```
std::min({0}); // That becomes an intializer_list<int> with one item.
```

That is standards compliant.

Answer (score 2):

#### How does `min` with `initializer_list` actually work?

This `min` function variant defers it's work to [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element), which finds minimum element in a range defined by a pair of iterators. [`std::initializer_list<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) is a lightweight proxy object that provides access to an array of objects of type `const T` as range `[begin(), end())`.

#### Simple variadic `min` function that takes one or more arguments:

```cxx
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Ts>
struct all_same {};

template <>
struct all_same<> {
    constexpr static bool value = true;
};

template <typename T>
struct all_same<T> {
    constexpr static bool value = true;
};

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Rest>
struct all_same<T, U, Rest...> {
    constexpr static bool value = std::is_same_v<T, U> && all_same<U, Rest...>::value;
};

template <typename... Ts>
inline constexpr bool all_same_v = all_same<Ts...>::value;

template <typename T>
constexpr const T& min(const T& value) {
    return value;
}

template <typename T, typename... U>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<all_same_v<T, U...>, const T&> min(const T& first,
                                                              const T& second,
                                                              const U&... rest) {
    return first <= second ? min(first, rest...) : min(second, rest...);
}

// min(1); // equals to 1
// min(4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3); // equals to 1
```

[<kbd>On Coliru</kbd>](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4112c3e4fdc1ea4)

Comment: Simpler variadic min: `template <typename ... T> constexpr std::common_type_t<T...> min(T... values) { return std::min<std::common_type_t<T...>>({values...}); }`